# How can I pass the current URL params to method for replacement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the [`Pager`](https://github.com/erichexter/twitter.bootstrap.mvc/blob/master/src/Bootstrap/HtmlHelpers/Paging.cs) HTML Helper class from `twitter.bootstrap.mvc`. It will build list of page links for Bootstrap.

How would I pass the current URL parameters to this function?

```
public static MvcHtmlString Pager(this HtmlHelper helper,
                                  int currentPage, int totalPages,
                                  Func<int, string> pageUrl,   <-- This
                                  string additionalPagerCssClass = "") {
    ...
    a.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i));
    ...
}
```

It is called like this:

```
@Html.Pager(Model.PageIndex, Model.TotalPages, x => Url.Action("Results", "Search", new { page = x }))
```

The `x => Url.Action("Results", "Search", new { page = x })` is the part that I don't know how to change. This is a search results page and has the search settings in the URL as parameters. For the paging to work, I need these params.

Is my only option to specify every single param and have them in the ViewModel as well as the URL?

Answer (score 1):

> Is my only option to specify every single param and have them in the
>   ViewModel as well as the URL?

It is probably not your only option, you could look at using `ViewData` or cookies for example, but it is probably the best option.

The ViewModel should really contain all the data required to render your view.  Given that your paging controls depend on this data, it is not unreasonable for it to be part of your ViewModel.

You View will still look reasonably tidy

e.g.

```
`@Html.Pager(Model.PageIndex, Model.TotalPages, x => Url.Action("Results", "Search", new { page = x, search = Model.Search, orderBy = Model.OrderBy }))`
```

If you have a lot of parameters t pass, you could enhance this by making a special "Paging" class which will hold all the details required for the paging, have this as a property of your model modify the HtmlHelper to accept this, to tidy up some of this code.

e.g.

```
public class PagingDetails 
{
   public int TotalPages { get; set; }
   public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
   public int TotalResults { get; set; }
   public string Search { get; set; }
   public string OrderBy { get; set; }
...other parameters...
}

public static MvcHtmlString Pager(this HtmlHelper helper,
                                  Func<int, string> pageUrl,  
                                  PagingDetails pagingDetails,                             
                                  string additionalPagerCssClass = "") 
{
   // need to tweak this to append extra parameters to resulting URL
}



`@Html.Pager(x => Url.Action("Results", "Search", new { page = x }, Model.PagingDetails))`
```